# How to control size of a SearchView in Toolbar

Tags: android, android-toolbar, searchview

I have a search icon and an overflow menu icon in the `Toolbar`, but when the `SearchView` is expanded, the overflow menu icon is moved.

How can I fix the overflow icon?

Here is the menu.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_item_search"
        android:icon="@drawable/quantum_ic_search_white_24"
        android:showAsAction="collapseActionView|always"
        android:title="@string/search"
        app:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView"
        app:showAsAction="always"/>

    <item android:title="@string/show_system_apps"
        android:id="@+id/menu_show_system_apps"
        app:showAsAction="never"/>

    <item android:title="@string/hide_system_apps"
        android:id="@+id/menu_hide_system_apps"
        app:showAsAction="never"/>

</menu>
```

Here is the picture of the moved overflow icon

[image]

Comment: Nothing is wrong. It's the feature of SearchView. If you want it to be fixed at the place try creating a EditText instead of searchView and changing Visibility by press of SearchButton in menu.

Comment: Thanks for reminding. But why does searchview has such a feature? I think the searchview is too broad for this use case. If I switch to landscape mode, it works well. But I cannot set the width of the searchview to a fixed size, it may change for different sizes of screen.